# Sort by two fields while being case insensitive in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with multiple fields, two being "name" and "brand". I want to sort this array by brand, and then sub-sort by name. The problem is that not all names or brands are capitalized, but I'd like them to be sorted in ABC order regardless. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

You should add some of what you have tried however ..

This might be what you're looking for, it will only look after the lower case problem you are having, your sorting can be done yourself! :)

```
var arrayList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    arrayList.push(item[i].toLowerCase());
}
arrayList.sort();
```

The `.toLowerCase()` should resolve your issue .

Or as i see from your question the same applies for : `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Well, my main issue is that I know how to sort lowercase and I know how to sort two fields, I'm just having trouble combining the two correctly.

Comment: Do them seperately if you like.. create a new array pushing all items to it as lowercase/uppercase.. then sort